# A trixy Mod_Rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite, symfony1

I have a site that I need to do a trixy mod_rewrite for! Here is the situation. I have domain.com I am using Symfony as my Framework and I need to be able to hit a module with a nothing but an ID in the main domain. Example for clarification:

```
example:

http://www.domain.com/web/index.php/module/show/id/1
Here is my url to the page I am interested in

http://www.domain.com/1
I want this page to go to the above page
*Note: ID can be a number OR a string i.e. /1 or /bobsHope
```

This issue I see with this is how do allow for any id/string and still have the entire rest of my site work. The possible solution I see here is that every other page always starts with /web

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you're best off if you can set `/web` as your DocumentRoot, either using a symlink or via httpd.conf

If you can do that, it's just a matter of creating a routing rule, e.g.

```
a_basic_route:
  url:   /:id
  param: { module: somemodule, action: someaction }
```

If you cannot, then I believe the following in your .htaccess will work together with the above routing rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```